# Using hensel's lemma

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: only above question]

I dont know why if f'(1)=0 mod3 , then f(1)=36 mod81 means there is no solution.

we dont need to test each step?
In mod3 's sold considering sol of mod9
And with sol of mod9. We decide sol of mod27 and ...   likewise i think we have to test each step but .. the account of problem doesnt seem to that
[image: number]

Comment: Proof : http://math453spring2009.wikidot.com/hensel-s-lemma

Comment: I know hensel's lemma but i dont know why in this problem, it doesn't test all.case like hensel's lemma?

Comment: You don't need Hensel's Lemma for this problem though. $$x^2+x+34\equiv x^2-80x+40^2-2\cdot 3^3\cdot 29\equiv 0\pmod{81}$$

$$\iff (x-40)^2\equiv 2\cdot 3^3\cdot 29\pmod{81}\implies 3^3\mid (x-40)^2$$

$$\implies 3^2\mid x-40\implies 3^4\mid (x-40)^2,$$

contradiction, because $3^4\nmid 2\cdot 3^3\cdot 29$.

Comment: how can find factor 2,3^3,29 ?